# how to check who and when clicked facebook like button

Tags: facebook, time

I using this to check how many likes are on my website

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://mywebsite.pl

My Question is:

How to check who and when clicked facebook like button on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to identify users who clicked a Like Button on your external Website, for privacy reasons. You can only see friends who liked the same URL by setting the "data-show-faces" flag in the Like Button Plugin.

You can subscribe to the `edge.create` event if you want to know when it gets clicked, but this still does not return WHO clicked it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe